# Why result is outputted to 1

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am having a simple program as shown below

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

  public:
    A()
    {
      int a();
      cout<<"\n value of A is:-  "<<a<<"\n\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  A obj;
  return 0;
}
```

The above program is outputting one, although I am not passing any value to variable `a`. Is it some task constructor is performing or some other type of default constructors are called, if I keep  () with any variable.

Same is happening for float datatype also.

It look simple but I want to understand the concept behind this. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: [The above program doesn't *compile*](http://ideone.com/tSKGHw), so I consider it's "output" highly suspect.

Comment: its compiling successfully.. with 0 build errors..
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: No, it doesn't compile. You wrote `<` instead of `<<` in the line starting with `cout`.

Comment: sorry its typo in question..corrected it...

Comment: Most vexing parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int a()` declares a function named `a`, taking no arguments and returning `int`. When you try to output a function, it gets converted to a function pointer, which in turn is converted to `bool`. The address of a function will always be non-null, so it gets converted to `true`, which is printed as 1.

Note however that you are violating the One Definition Rule: you're not allowed to take the address of a function if the function lacks a definition. However, the compiler is not required to diagnose violations of the ODR. In this particular case, the compiler decides it doesn't care about the actual address, since it knows that it will be non-null no matter what.

If you want to declare an `int` and value-initialize it, the correct syntax is

```
int a{};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d10bdd34c238ab6

Comment: You can also initialize an integer like this: `int a(42);`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), `int a();` is function declaration, which takes no parameters and returns `int`. When you output it will decay to function pointer which is not null, and then converted to `bool` `true`, so the result is `1` here.

If you just want to declare it you could

```
int a;
```

If you want to declare and initialize it you could

```
int a = 1; // initialized with the specified value
int a{2};  // initialized with the specified value, since C++11
int a{};   // initialized with 0, since C++11
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that `int a();` declares a variable. That is not correct. You are declaring a function named `a` with no parameters that returns `int`.

What you probably intended is `int a;`.

Also, you *must* initialize a variable before reading it (like in your output statement) or else the program will contain undefined behaviour and has no meaning and the compiler is free to generate whatever code it likes. Not a situation you want to be in, so what you *really* want is `int a = 0;`.

As to why you get `1` as output; the `a` is being converted to `bool` (`true`) which prints as `1`.

Comment: Actually, there's no (general) function pointer overload of `operator<<`. `a` is being converted to `bool`. At that point, it must print 1.